# UV Mapping multiple objects using same material

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

I have a blend file with MANY blocks that I use in a game. They are all separate objects, but use the same materials.

I have unwrapped them and then manually size the UV until the grass looks almost the same. This takes a while and is never exactly the same.

[image: Example of objects]

I found this material setup somewhere (I wish I remember), and although it looks fine in Blender, after exporting it to FBX and importing it into Unity, the smaller block has different look.
[image: What I have tried]

The smaller block is on the left. (Unity)
[image: Unity]

Is there away to do this automatically ? Change the UV size to match the blocks world size ? Or do I need to update it manually ?

Mr Zak pointed out Textools. It has a function that does exactly what I am looking for.
[image: Textools]

Texture density can be matched. So if you "apply wall paper" to a small room and then a huge room the wall paper looks the same in both rooms. I only know how to do this manually, by scaling the UV of the bigger room till it matches the small room. It seems Textools does this work for you.

I would still love to learn how to do this myself.  Like I stated I have been doing this by eye and would like to know if there is a better way.

[image: Manual Scaling]

Comment: Your shader is wrong, because you have to plug the UV to the vector of the texture to see the UV. You plugged the object into it, so the UV won't affect the result.

Comment: Hard to tell from your screenshots. I can only guess that you are using "Material View" in Blender which doesn't necessarily deliver an accurate representation of your models. You can also create a smaller version of your file with only two blocks, pack your textures with it and upload it to [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) for us to check. Use the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/133486/edit) to update your question with the provided link.

Comment: [TexTools](https://blenderartists.org/t/textools-for-blender/700811) addon is designed to equalize textl density for different objects quickly, in this example it would mean picking density from one block and applying it to another. Exporting object with Object coordinates might not work because other application has to be set up to use the same coordinates to provide the same result (if it can do that which isn't necessary).

Comment: @MrZak The "Texel Density tools" is exactly what i am looking for thank you. I still want to learn how to do this on for my self.

Comment: It is shown by the author of the addon in BA thread I linked http://renderhjs.net/textools/blender/images/demo_texel_density.gif. Generally it's just click picker button on one block and then click Apply on the other

Comment: @MrZak Im just trying to work out why I dont see the Texel Density tool.